# Cannot change resolution / Cannot use Seamless Windows feature on Lubuntu 14.10 running on VirtualBox 4.3.14

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution, lubuntu, guest-additions

My two issues are not being able to change video resolutions. I am stuck at 640x480. Also I cannot use the Seamless Windows feature in virtual box as it's greyed out. I am stumped, I can use some of the features such as clipboard sharing and I've even setup folder sharing from Host to Guest. I cannot use the auto resize function when I change the window, can't change resolutions or use seamless windows.

I have installed Guest Additions version

```
$ modinfo vboxguest
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/vboxguest.ko
version:        4.3.14
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     53E0D047D01503FC05EFEB9
alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Many of the features are working, shared clipboard, shared folders.

```
$ ps ax | grep -i vbox
1305 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/VBoxService
1562 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --clipboard
1570 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --display
1572 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --seamless
1577 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop
2124 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -i vbox
```

The video module appears to be loaded

```
$ lsmod | grep vbox
vboxsf                 43691  1 
vboxvideo              12669  0 
vboxguest             260944  6 vboxsf
drm                   310919  2 vboxvideo


$ modinfo vboxvideo
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/vboxvideo.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
version:        4.3.14
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Graphics Card
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     819A8212D6CDC4DDED68716
alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000BEEFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        drm
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Xrandr readout

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
640x480        73.0*
```

DKMS and generic-linux-headers were installed before installing VBox Additions

```
$ sudo apt-get install dkms linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Download guest additions and mount it. You will now see a dvd inserted in virtual machine. Run the appropriate installer. Now shut down guest machine.

Next, in your host computer's command line, type

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution 1272,920
```

And replace the last two numbers with the screen res of your choice.

Next time you boot into the guest OS, your screen res will be the way you want it.